# Load Resource-file in C++ / Qt Visual Studio

Tags: qt, visual-studio-2008

I'm trying to load a resource file with the following code:

```
QResource::registerResource("myResources.rcc");
```

The problem is that it doesn't load the resources as it said something like "File not found".
When i start my executeable by hand the resource file loads correctly, but when i start it via   visual studio it fails.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image]

That Working Director was empty..